# commandLink don't put a link on screen

Tags: jsf, label, commandlink

i'm starting with jsf and i'm having a issue with this project.

The following command don't create a link that i need to go to the next page, only give me "Novo usuário" written on the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Financeiro</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Financeiro</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.novo}">Novo Usuário</h:commandLink>    
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

I also tried this variation, without success:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{usuarioBean.novo}" value="Novo usuário"/>
```

This is the method called by `#{usuarioBean.novo}`

```
public class UsuarioBean {
    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    private String confirmarSenha;

    public String novo() { 
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.usuario.setAtivo(true);
        return "/publico/usuario"; 
    }
}
```

P.S. i'm br, so i'm sorry in advance for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use the value attribute.

`<h:commandLink action="#{action.doActions}" value = "Novo Usuário" />`

Comment: It's still not showing up on the screen? the action you're wanting to perform isn't executing? What doesn't work?

Comment: it's still showing only "novo usuario" written on the screen, and doesn't perform action because it doesn't give the link...

Comment: Now i'm doing like this `<a href="publico/usuario.jsf" >Novo Usuário</a>` , redirect to the next page, but the function `#{usuarioBean.novo}` is not in use.

Comment: So what is the issue?